# How to return an ArrayList in ResponseEntity?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'd like to return an ArrayList in the response of a REST endpoint.

I'm trying the following but not working.

```
    @GetMapping(value="/{userName}", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<ArrayList<RoleResponseDTO>> getUserRoles(@PathVariable (value="userName") String userName){
                
        ArrayList<RoleResponseDTO> roleResponseDTOList; 

        roleResponseDTOList = userRoleService.getUserRoles(userName);
        
        return new ResponseEntity<ArrayList<RoleResponseDTO>>(roleResponseDTOList, HttpStatus.OK);
        
    }
```

I get the following exception.

I can't see what comes before that in the console.

Seems it reaches the console buffer limit.

Compilation goes successfully.

This error messages are displayed after I submit the GET request in Postman.

The error happens when this line executes:

```
return new ResponseEntity<ArrayList<RoleResponseDTO>>(roleResponseDTOList, HttpStatus.OK);
```

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
```

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Do you get an error?

Comment: Should use `List` rather than `ArrayList`

Comment: what means "not working"? any exception?

Comment: I added the error message. But can't see error messages that comes before it.

Comment: @Zack Macomber I tried with ```List```. Same error.

Comment: Your issue isn't related with the fact your returning the list but rather with the serialization of RoleResponseDTO. Can you provide a snippet of that dto? also, The beginning of the exception would help as well.

Comment: @CaptainAye I agree that the beginning of the exception would help. But those are the exact first lines displayed in the console. Console is not displaying what came before that. I think it's because it reached it's limit of content to be displayed.

Comment: @CaptainAye Yes, the DTO is not well formatted. That should be it. Will need to do some rework on it. Thank you.

Comment: You have posted an incomplete stacktrace, without the actual error message, and probably parts missing at the end (e.g. caused by parts).

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel Agreed. The reason for that is that like I mentioned in the question and comments is that the console is not displaying the actual error. It keeps adding those messages forever for more than the console has space to handle and then the actual error goes out of the console area.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an approach similar to the following:

```
@GetMapping(value="/{userName}", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<List<RoleResponseDTO>> getUserRoles(
                                @PathVariable (value="userName") String userName){
    final List<RoleResponseDTO> response = userRoleService.getUserRoles(userName);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(response));
}
```